# validating dynamically generated elements problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate some elements that are dynamically generated with jquery.

here is the code I have

```
    $newInsert = $("#aconditional").clone();
    $test = $newInsert.find("[name='trailvalue']");
    $test.rules("add",{
        required: true
    });
```

trailvalue is just an element inside the generated div.

when I run javascript with this I get a javascript error
"$test.rules is not a function"

I have validation working inside other parts of the same html file, so I sure I am including the validation plugin correctly.

anyone see something I dont see ?

I tried this as well for testing purposes

```
        $("[name='trailvalue']").each(function (index,element){
        $(this).rules("add",{
            required:true
        });
    });
```

got a slight different error "a is null"

thank you

Answer (score 1):

`clone` doesn't copy events by default. Therefore the `rules()` events are not cloned and ultimately not bound to `$test`. Check out the docs - http://api.jquery.com/clone/ and try the following:

```
$newInsert = $("#aconditional").clone(true);
```

Comment: I am adding it to the element after I clone it though not before